# Google chrome goes to java update notification page

Tags: java, google-chrome

Always I enter in my application in google chrome browser, it goes to java update page with this following message:

**"We have detected you are using Google Chrome and might be unable to use the Java plugin from this browser. Starting with Version 42 (released April 2015), Chrome has disabled the standard way in which browsers support plugins. More info"**

The problem: I can't update java because my application does not run in the last version of java. I need to keep it in an old version.

[image: Java update page]

Is there a way to run the application on google chrome updated e java with an old version?

Answer (score 5):

This problem is because the browser will no longer support the NPAPI protocol, which is used by these plugins to communicate with Google Chrome

To solve this:

- In Chrome's address bar, type "chrome: // flags" (without the quotes) and press Enter
- Locate the item "Enable NPAPI" activate it.
- Click on "reboot now" botton

Comment: It might be worth adding to this answer that come September Chrome won't let you do this any more.